# Eclipse crashes when start up on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, crash

I just find eclipse always crashes on my laptop with ubuntu 12.04 installed.
And I have tried different versions of eclipse (3.6/3.7/4.2).
I also tried many other eclipse based applications, none of the applications works.
It worked fine several days ago, so I guess it should be something wrong with the latest libc update.

The error message is

```
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00040000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000004 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000080
Handler1=B4BDAA36 Handler2=B4BB0021 InaccessibleAddress=00000000
EDI=08306E58 ESI=92F2BB43 EAX=BFB87E14 EBX=B7754FF4
ECX=00000000 EDX=0000000B
EIP=B76E15C5 ES=007B DS=007B ESP=BFB85324
EFlags=00010246 CS=0073 SS=007B EBP=B75AE6C0
Module=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Module_base_address=B75AF000
Target=2_40_20130114_134867 (Linux 3.2.0-39-generic-pae)
CPU=x86 (4 logical CPUs) (0x1f1439000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
(0xB4BA3B76 [libj9prt24.so+0xbb76])
(0xB4BAF66C [libj9prt24.so+0x1766c])
(0xB4BA3C09 [libj9prt24.so+0xbc09])
(0xB4BA3D2C [libj9prt24.so+0xbd2c])
(0xB4BA39A8 [libj9prt24.so+0xb9a8])
(0xB4BAF66C [libj9prt24.so+0x1766c])
(0xB4BA3A1C [libj9prt24.so+0xba1c])
(0xB4BDB771 [libj9vm24.so+0xf771])
(0xB4BDB3F1 [libj9vm24.so+0xf3f1])
(0xB4BAF66C [libj9prt24.so+0x1766c])
(0xB4BDABD6 [libj9vm24.so+0xebd6])
(0xB4BB0199 [libj9prt24.so+0x18199])
(0xB779740C)
---------------------------------------
```

Does anyone hit the same issue recently? Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I also have a segmentation violation in the JRE when I try to run eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 is not a supported platform for Eclipse 4.2.  10.04 is, however, with IBM Java 6 SR9.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.2.php#TargetOperatingEnvironments

As you are using IBM Java, I would suggest using OpenJDK or Oracle Java instead.  Note:  This is for running Eclipse itself - you kan still use IBM Java for your own code inside Eclipse.